# Python: Putting Charater in front or behind a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I want to write a couple characters into a file where there is already text inside. What would be the code to add characters to the front of the file and to the back of the text file if I want the text that was initially in the file to remain in the center?

Comment: I used append to add bytes in the back but as for the front I tried using file.seek(0,0) to get to the front but had no luck in adding bits to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add some text to the end of your file, simply open it in append mode and then write to it as usual.

```
open('file.txt', 'a')
```

If you want to add something to the beginning of the file, and you don't mind loading the contents of the file  temporarily into memory.

```
addedText = 'Hello World!'
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as myFile:
    filecontents = myFile.read()
    myFile.seek(0,0)
    f.write(addedText.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + filecontents)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to open a file and keep its content you have to open the file in append mode. Also have a look at:

[file.seek (can be used to set the files current position)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek)

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in any knows underlying file systems that allows to *insert* bytes into a file. You can only :

- add bytes (characters) at the end of the file (append mode)
- rewrite bytes in place anywhere in the file
- truncate a file at current position.

So if you want to add anything not at the end of the file, the common way (that is used by many text editors) is :

- rename the old file to a temp name (it is known as a backup copy)
- create a new file with the original name and write what you want to it (here the prefix, the original content and the postfix)
- (optionaly) delete the backup copy.

That way allows you to recover your file even if bad things occur while writing the new copy : you can at least get the previous copy and restart your edition.